# Alarm Manager not working is case on changing system date and time in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am testing Alarm Manager but on changing system time no broadcast is received.

However in the normal case (without changing system's time) this works fine. Why is this so?

```
val alarmIntent = Intent(mContext, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, alarmIntent, 0)

            val manager = mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, AppConstants.NOTIFICATION_HOUR)
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)

            manager.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent
            )
```

Comment: It's obvious because when you change a system time, the time that you already set to alarm manager becoming more or less than initial time that was before changing the time

Comment: @easy_breezy I have set the alarm to daily 10 AM. Now I change the systems time to 9:59 AM to the next day after scheduling the alarm. But I don't get the broadcast this time (when the time is 10 AM). 

please guide me with the root cause & its soultion